# Setting custom homepage for Wordpress blog

Tags: wordpress

I need to have custom page as homepage and I know how to do that (http://www.lancelhoff.com/how-to-set-a-wordpress-static-front-page/), but when I set custom page as homepage, I cannot have latest posts page. So how can I link to latest post pages, because it's address isn't anymore root path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new Page, for example "Blog", then goto:

http://yourdomain.tld/wp-admin/options-reading.php

and change "Front Page" to for example Home (your homepage) and Posts page to your Blog Page (in this example "Blog")

Now you can link in your `header.php` your Blog Page:

```
<a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/blog" title="Our Posts">Blog</a>
```

and if you save this, you can click on this and will see your Posts. Or you can create a custom Page Template like this Code: [WordPress Custom Theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148825/wordpress-custom-page-template/2149164#2149164) and set this as your Page Template of your Blog. But the First way is easier...